# Turn 2010 Q1 to datetime as 2010-3-31

Tags: python, pandas, time-series, data-cleaning

[image]

How to find a smart solution to turn Year_Q to datetime? I tried to use

```
pd.to_datetime(working_visa_nationality['Year_Q'])
```

but got error says that this cannot be recognized. So I tried a stupid way as:

```
working_visa_nationality['Year'] = working_visa_nationality.Year_Q.str.slice(0,4)
working_visa_nationality['Quarter'] = working_visa_nationality.Year_Q.str.slice(6,8)
```

[image]

And now I found a problem: it is true that I can groupby data by the year, but it is difficult to include the quarter to my line plot.

So how to make 2010 Q1 like 2010-3-31?

Comment: Please see https://stackoverflow.com/q/46350531 if it helps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I a bit changed [`MaxU` answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46350953/2901002):

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Year_Q': ['2010 Q1', '2015 Q2']})

df['Dates']  = pd.PeriodIndex(df['Year_Q'].str.replace(' ', ''), freq='Q').to_timestamp()
print (df)
    Year_Q      Dates
0  2010 Q1 2010-01-01
1  2015 Q2 2015-04-01
```

EDIT:

```
df['Dates']  = pd.PeriodIndex(df['Year_Q'].str.replace(' ', ''), freq='Q').to_timestamp(how='e')
print (df)
    Year_Q      Dates
0  2010 Q1 2010-03-31
1  2015 Q2 2015-06-30
```

Comment: Great! but how to make the dates the end of the last day of the quarter ?    2010-01-01 ->2010-03-31

Comment: @ZakkYang - Check edited answer, need parameetr `how`

Answer (score 0):

My solution with regex.

```
df['Year_Q'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Year_Q'].str.replace(r'\ [Q1]+', '-3-31'))
```

Answer (score 0):

```
working_visa_nationality['Dates']  = pd.PeriodIndex(working_visa_nationality['Year_Q'].str.replace(' ', ''), freq='Q').to_timestamp() + pd.offsets.QuarterEnd()

working_visa_nationality['Dates']  = pd.PeriodIndex(working_visa_nationality['Year_Q'].str.replace(' ', ''), freq='Q').to_timestamp(how='end')
```

both of them work well.
Thank you all and I did some experiment.